# Problems with updating a Django form with information from another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm basically building functionality to update a form with values from one table in my models.py, the form will populate the initial values with that table (leads) and upon submitting the information, the form will populate another model (leads)

These is my models.py

```
class Leads(models.Model):

    project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expected_revenue = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=14, default_currency='USD')
    expected_licenses = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select_country)')
    status = models.CharField(choices=[('Open', 'Open'), ('Closed', 'Closed'), ('Canceled', 'Canceled')], max_length=10)
    estimated_closing_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    services = models.CharField(choices=[('Illumination Studies', 'Illumination Studies'),
                                  ('Training', 'Training'),('Survey Design Consultancy', 'Survey Design Consultancy'),
                                  ('Software License', 'Software License'),
                                  ('Software Development','Software Development')], max_length=40)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default='agent',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    point_of_contact = models.ForeignKey(Client, default='agent',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Deal(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='id')
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="agent")
    service = models.ForeignKey(Leads, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service')
    closing_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='client')
    licenses = models.ForeignKey(Leads,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='license')
    revenue = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py

```
class NewDealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = ['project_id','agent','client','company','service', 'licenses','revenue','comments']
```

```
@login_required
def close_lead(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        deal_form = NewDealForm(request.POST)
        print(deal_form)
        if deal_form.is_valid():
            deal_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated the status from open to Close')
            id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
            obj = Leads.objects.get(project_id=id)
            obj.status = "Closed"
            obj.save(update_fields=['status'])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:

            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your Form')
    else:
        id = request.GET.get('project_id', '')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Leads, project_id=id)

        m = obj.__dict__
        keys = Leads.objects.get(project_id=m['project_id'])

        form_dict = {'project_id': keys.project_id,
                     'agent': keys.agent,
                     'client': keys.point_of_contact,
                     'company': keys.company,
                     'service': keys.services,
                     'licenses':keys.expected_licenses
                     }
        print(form_dict)
        form = NewDealForm(request.POST or None, initial=form_dict)

    return render(request,
                  "account/close_lead.html",
                  {'form': form})
```

My question is why all the values are populated except the service field?

[image: Service field not populated]

Does anyone have any idea, the output of my dictionary looks correct, and it contains the information for service, but somehow this is not passed to the form?

{'project_id': 1, 'agent': <Profile: fcolina>, 'client': <Client: Zack M.>, 'company': <Company: E3>, 'service': 'Software License', 'licenses': 3}

As you can see, service has an actual value

Answer (score 0):

In your `Deal` model, the `services` field is a foreign key to `Leads`:

```py
class Deal(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Leads)
```

And you try to populate it with the value of `services` field in `Leads`, thats is a string.

```py
class Leads(models.Model):
    services = models.CharField()
```

Viewing your models, you would need populate the `services`  field with a `Leads` instance:

```py
form_dict = {'project_id': keys.project_id,
                     'agent': keys.agent,
                     'client': keys.point_of_contact,
                     'company': keys.company,
                     'service': keys, # <-- point to Leads
                     'licenses':keys.expected_licenses
                     }
```

Comment: Tonio - Thanks, but that's what I'm doing,  keys = Leads.objects.get(project_id=m['project_id']) , the variable keys is taking the objects for the particular model, if I add only keys, the result is an integer, in this case, the id of the lead (observation)  in leads models

Comment: See = {'project_id': 3, 'agent': <Profile: fcolina>, 'client': <Client: Ket>, 'company': <Company: Ex3>, 'service': <Leads: 3>, 'licenses': 4}

Comment: @FranciscoColina, it is not an integer, it is an instance of `Leads`. I think that is what `NewDealForm` expects to find in the `service` field.I don't know what exact instance you should use.

Comment: it should technically be keys.services as per my code above